# Como corregir este problema al hacer dir en un cliente servidor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

[image: IMAGEN DE ENTRADA ACTUAL]

Estoy haciendo una conexion cliente-servidor

Por el lador del servidor el objetivo es hacer un dir y que se ejecute en la maquina cliente, luego la maquina cliente envia esta informacion al servidor. Pero mi problema es que al recibir esta informacion, la salida en la terminal del servidor se ve incomprensible.

En la primera foto es como recibo la entrada y en la segunda foto es como quiero que la entrada se vea. ALGUNA AYUDA CON ESO... Gracias de ante mano comunidad

[image: COMO ESPERO RECIBIR LA ENTRADA]

CODIGO DEL SERVIDOR

```
import socket

host = "192.168.0.34"
puerto = 4444
buffer = 30000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, puerto))
    sock.listen(5)
    print("\n\n[+]Esperando conexion\n")

    cliente, direccion = sock.accept()
    

    with cliente:
        print("\n[+]Conexion establecida")

        while True:
            comandos = input("\nShell->:")
            cliente.send(comandos.encode('utf-8'))
            data = cliente.recv(buffer)
            print(data)
```

CODIGO DEL LADO DEL CLIENTE

```
import socket
import subprocess

host = "192.168.0.34"
puerto = 4444
buffer = 30000


def ejecutar_comandos(comandos):
    return subprocess.check_output(comandos, shell=True)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as servidor:
    servidor.connect((host, puerto))

    while True:
        data = servidor.recv(buffer)
        comandos = data.decode('utf-8')
        result = ejecutar_comandos(comandos)
        servidor.send(result)
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué quieres decir con el orden correcto? ¿Cómo esperarías que fuera la salida? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la información que hace falta.

Comment: Editado amigo...

Comment: Cuál es el código que genera esto?

Comment: @Alfabravo EDITE LA PREGUNTA Y PUSE EL CODIGO AMIGO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La documentación de [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) menciona que la respuesta está en `bytes`

> By default, this function will return the data as encoded bytes.

Es por eso que al inicio del texto aparece una `b`. Esta respuesta hay que decodificarla en el lado del servidor para que se imprima como tu deseas.

Ejemplo:

```
import socket

host = "192.168.0.34"
puerto = 4444
buffer = 30000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, puerto))
    sock.listen(5)
    print("\n\n[+]Esperando conexion\n")

    cliente, direccion = sock.accept()
    

    with cliente:
        print("\n[+]Conexion establecida")

        while True:
            comandos = input("\nShell->:")
            cliente.send(comandos.encode('utf-8'))
            data = cliente.recv(buffer)
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

**Edición:** Gracias a la observación de Abulafia es posible que la codificación sea `cp1252` por lo que la última línea quedaría así:

```
print(data.decode('cp1252'))
```

Comment: Si observas la cadena que recibía el OP verás que la palabra "número" se muestra como `n\xa3mero` lo que es un indicio de que el encoding no es UTF-8 (la ú serían 2 bytes en ese caso). Lo más probable es que sea cp1252, puesto que el operativo del cliente parece ser Windows y estar en español.

Comment: Gracias @abulafia, he agregado una edición

Comment: Gracias colegas. Me han ayudado con mi poblema y mas que agradecido ya que en esta comunidad cada dia se aprende mas.

efectivamente la solucion es que al decodear la informacion proveniente del cliente de hacerlo con 'cp1252' y no con utf-8.... Gracias a todos